# How to merge similar consecutive rows and add the corresponding numerical values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like:

[image]

then I want to merge same LITHO_UNIT occurring consecutively and add the corresponding THICKNESS & RECOVERY values. The result should:

[image]

how this could be done efficiently in Python Pandas.

Comment: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

If the current name of `LITHO_UNIT` is different from the previous row, start a new group. You can compute `sum` for each group:

```
# Create groups
g = df['LITHO_UNIT'].ne(df['LITHO_UNIT'].shift()).cumsum()

# Compute sum on numeric columns
out = df.select_dtypes('number').groupby(g).sum().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   THICKNESS  RECOVERY
0          1         1
1          3         3
2          3         3

>>> df
  LITHO_UNIT  THICKNESS  RECOVERY
0         CZ          1         1
1         CY          1         1
2         CY          2         2
3         CZ          3         3
```

If you want to apply different math operations on columns, use `agg`:

```
out = (df.groupby(g, as_index=False)
         .agg({'LITHO_UNIT': 'first',
               'THICKNESS': 'sum',
               'RECOVERY': 'mean'}))
print(out)

# Output
  LITHO_UNIT  THICKNESS  RECOVERY
0         CZ          1       1.0
1         CY          3       1.5
2         CZ          3       3.0
```